# Suffix "-halber" in "sicherheitshalber"

Tags: etymology, suffix

What is the meaning behind the suffix "-halber" in the word [sicherheitshalber](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sicherheitshalber)? Is it like "to be on the safe side/half"? Still, if so, why does it come with the "-er"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Sicherheitshalber" is a composition of the noun "Sicherheit" with the preposition "[halber](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/halber_aufgrund_fuer_wegen)", which means "for reasons of ..." or "due to ...". According to the Duden it is derived from an old word for "Hälfte" or "Seite", so you could maybe think of it as "to be on the side of ...".

So "sicherheitshalber" means "to be on the safe side", "for safety reasons" or "to be sure".

Comment: This is exactly the same metaphor as "erring on the side of caution", so "sicherheitshalber" is in fact a central instance of this pattern - but there are others, e.g. "der Vollständigkeit halber".

Comment: There is something very similar in English

> on the behalf of safety

Here, "half" is used to express the idea of reason, too.